# bootstrap modal dialog is closed immediately

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

when opening an bootstrap modal dialog, the modal window is closed immediately - seeing it only when debugging. See my code:
Html of the opener:

```
<span>
    <span>
        <button type="button" (click)="openDialog()">
            Open dialog
        </button>
    </span>
</span>
```

component code:

```
export class dialogOpener implements OnInit {

    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }
    openDialog()
    {
        const modalRef : NgbModalRef = this.modalService.open(modalDialogComponent);
    }
}
```

Modal window Html:

```
<p>modalDialog works!</p>
```

component code:

```
export class modalDialogComponent {

  constructor(private activeModal: NgbActiveModal, private modalService: NgbModal) { }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
        ...
        AppComponent,
        modalDialogComponent, 

  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents:[modalDialogComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What can be wrong here ?

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't really know. But have you tried making `NgbActiveModal` a public class in your `modalDialogComponent`?

Comment: @Francisco Santorelli - yes, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Seems good to me, have you tried in an other browser ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a css issue:
The modal was there but faded away for some reason due to ngb-modal-window -> modal ->fade
css class: opacity:0;